# Openid redirect not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I tried this example for openid in 
 http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx
I applied the same code in my newly created project , I get this error when i click the google icon in the logon page. I din change any code from the sample project I downloaded from this website, still I get this error .

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do we know what code you are using ? Consider posting some code.

Comment: I said I'm using the same code from the mentioned link,

Comment: Why have you masked localhost port number??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds just like an MVC controller problem. your Account controller is expected to have an Authenticate action. And since we're seeing a 404, I suggest you investigate what's wrong with your routes.

Keep in mind that this URL should respond to both GET and POST  requests.

Comment: I change the default route to "Account" and "LogOn" such that login page appears first, This gives me the error. how to return the url from the controller?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. I have been using the DNOA library and I'm stuck at a problem. Couple you please help me out - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17903704/804503. Thanks