# How to Redirect to openid provider from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, dotnetopenauth

I use mvc3/razor in my code,
I have a homecontroller(index.cshtml) to load a homepage.Now I created Accountcontroller (Login.cshtml) to show openidlogin page inorder to enter the homepage.
When load the homecontroller and then manually type "Account/login " in the address bar, everything is working fine.
After I set Account and login in routeconfig.cs , openid icons does not redirect to the respective pages, instead showing 404 error, like this 
[Openid redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870104/openid-redirect-not-working)
I found the exact place of the error.
This is my paage source code of the obtained output:

```
<form action="&#47;" method="post">    <div>
```

But this line need to load as `<form action="&#47;Account&#47;Login" method="post">    <div>` in order to work properly.
I dunno how to change the controller.

this is my login.cstml file:

```
@model project.Models.LogOnModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}
<h2>
    Log On</h2>
<p>
    Please enter your username and password. @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")
    if you don't have an account.
</p>
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/openidSite.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/openid-shadow.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/openid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openid-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openid-jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            openid.init('openid_identifier');
        });
    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])" method="post" id="openid_form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify" />
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login using OpenID</legend>
        <div class="openid_choice">
            <p>
                Please click your account provider:</p>
            <div id="openid_btns">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="openid_input_area">
            @Html.TextBox("openid_identifier")
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <p>
                OpenID is service that allows you to log-on to many different websites using a single
                indentity. Find out <a href="http://openid.net/what/">more about OpenID</a> and
                <a href="http://openid.net/get/">how to get an OpenID enabled account</a>.</p>
        </noscript>
        <div>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName))
                {
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenID)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenID)
                </div>
                <p class="button">


                    @Html.ActionLink("New User ,Register", "Register", new { OpenID = Model.OpenID })
                </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    //user exist 
                <p class="buttonGreen">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Welcome , @Model.UserName, Continue..." </a>
                </p>

                }
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Or Login Normally</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <p >
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```